# Rendering partial shown card on next page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, pagination

I have implemented a custom pagination where I want to render the cards which are shown partially should be rendered in next page as full.

This is the part where pagination section logic is added.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const containerWidth = parentRef?.current?.offsetWidth;
    const userCardWidth = 140;
    const cardWidth = 340;
    const newCardsPerPage = Math.ceil(
      (containerWidth - userCardWidth) / cardWidth
    );
    setCardsPerPage(newCardsPerPage);
  }, []);

  const defaultCardCount = 4;

  const totalPages = Math.ceil(defaultCardCount / cardsPerPage);

  const startIdx = (currentPage - 1) * cardsPerPage;
  const endIdx = currentPage + cardsPerPage;

  const handlePaginationClick = (_, page) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
  };
```

I am not getting an idea how to show the partial card on the next page if there was partial cards in the current pages.

Can check in responsive screen sizes to see the issue.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/nice-frog-stpmcx?codemirror=1)

Any help will be appreciated